# Spring Data MongoDB sort performance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm seeing significant differences in Spring Data MongoDB sort performance, depending on the direction. I'm sorting on one property and have indices in both directions. When sorting ascending, the response time is around 80 ms, when sorting descending it's around 2.7 s. **Native queries** take 5 ms and 50 ms, respectively. Queries for subsequent pages are somewhat faster, around 1 s.

The 2.7 s is unacceptable for my application, is there anything I can do?

Controller:

```
String q = URLDecoder.decode(query);
Sort.Direction d = Sort.Direction.ASC;

if (direction == -1) {
    d = Sort.Direction.DESC;
}

String[] properties = sort.split(",");
Sort s = new Sort(d, Arrays.asList(properties));
Pageable p = new PageRequest(page, size, s);

List<Employer> list = employerRepository.find(q, p);
```

Repository:

```
@Override
public List<Employer> find(String query, Pageable page) {
    Query q = new BasicQuery(query).with(page);
    return mongoTemplate.find(q, Employer.class);
}
```

**Update 1:** I have enabled profiling on MongoDB, and the native and Spring Data queries look identical. So it seems the bottleneck is in `mongoTemplate.find(q, Employer.class);`.

Comment: have you tried putting an explicit index on the property? should make things faster - we're currently investigating and having an index seems to influence the results massively.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding `.withHint("myindexname")` and it dramatically improves performance. Surprisingly (for me at least), when I remove it again, performance remains good. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Spring Data cannot directly be blamed for the rather poor performance you're experiencing though there's a connection between `sort`, `DBCursor` and `Pageable`.

Spring Data uses a `DBCursor` to read values from a particular `DBCollection`. According to the `Pageable` parameter provided `sort`, `skip` and `limit` is set. After query execution the `DBCursor` is closed as you would expect.

So obviously you'd get better performance if you could reuse the cursor in between but this would introduce shared state that would cause other problems.

But let's have a closer look at what happens when we try to page through results, not reusing the cursor, with and without sort using the plain MongoDB driver API only.

For the example we use a collection with 10.000 `Person` elements with a name in range “foo0” to “foo10000”.

```
for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < 1000; pageNumber++) {
    DBCursor c = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "foo*")))
        .skip(pageNumber * 10)//
        .limit(10)//
        .sort(new BasicDBObject("name", -1)); // comment this line to see the difference

    DBObject o = null
    while (c.hasNext()) {
        o = c.next();
    }
    c.close();
}
```

This takes `48278 ms` on my machine, without the sort clause this drops to `2862 ms`.

Since this behaviour also happens if you don’t use Spring Data MongoDB I think that this cause for this problem is more likely to be found in the MongoDB java driver, but at this time I could not find a matching issue in the MongoDB issue tracker...

Comment: what happens if you remove the `while`-loop and close the cursor immediately?

Comment: @injecteer in that case nothing will ever be fetched from MongoDB... quite fast - but not sure if that would make sense? Or am I missing something?